# SQL Server Express - how to prevent copying database into debug folder?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, connection-string, sql-server-express

I'm creating a simple windows forms application using local SQL Server Express database as a data source. During debug the database file is copied into debug folder, everything works fine, but that's not what I want. I'd like to use only one copy of the database file.

Solution I found was hard coding path to the database file in connection string:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\db.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance = true
```

So, is there a more intelligent way of configuring VS to use only one db file, rather than hard coding it's path in connection string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole *User Instance and AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! When running your app in Visual Studio, it will be copying around the `.mdf` file (from your `App_Data` directory to the output directory - typically `.\bin\debug` - where you app runs) and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

The **REAL** solution in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Management Studio Express (if you haven't already)
2. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `MyDatabase`)
3. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server), and **let the server** handle all the file-related details; don't mess around with physical files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Comment: @ralphspoon: ***YES !!***